# using jq how do you query from variable which has json

Tags: shell, jq

How do a query a variable which has json value using jq. Below the command returs a json assigns to `activity` variable. But from `activity` variable not sure how to query using jq?

```
activity=`aws autoscaling describe-scaling-activities --profile mfa --auto-scaling-group-name cb-citation-needed --max-items 1`
```

When I try below it the variable activityCause is empty.

```
activityCause=$activity| jq -r '.Activities[].Cause'
```

or

```
activityCause=`$activity| jq -r '.Activities[].Cause'` i get error for this one
```

However when I try to query in one single command it works

```
activityCause=`aws autoscaling describe-scaling-activities --profile mfa --auto-scaling-group-name cb-citation-needed --max-items 1 | jq -r '.Activities[].Cause'`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first command assigns the JSON to the `activity` variable.

The second command, need's to be altert to 'feed' the json through the pipe since in `activityCause=$activity` `$activity` is interpreted as a command, and not the JSON;

1. Use [bash Here](https://linux.die.net/abs-guide/x15683.html)

   ```
   activityCause=$(jq -r '.Activities[].Cause' <<< "$activity")
   ```
2. Use *oldschool* echo:

   ```
   activityCause=$(echo "$activity" | jq -r '.Activities[].Cause')
   ```

Comment: Tip: `echo` can mess up some strings, and works differently on different systems. `printf '%s' "$activity"` is more reliable.